# Re-using Projects Labels in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

Im thinking there HAS to be a better way to do this, but if I make a new project in gitlab I have to re-create ALL the labels from scratch for the new project.

So far, I haven't found a decent way to "copy" labels from another project so I don't have to recreate a ton of labels each time. I know it's a small task but it's one of those annoying tasks that I feel you should be able to do automatically instead of manually making each one for the 10th time.

Is there a way I can do this currently? Even if it's duplicating some "fake" project that has all the labels already in it?

Comment: which edition of gitlab do you use? community or enterprise ?

Comment: It's the Community edition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a little utility that I found called [gitlab-copy](https://github.com/gotsunami/gitlab-copy) to copy the labels.
It was written to copy issues, and also copy labels, but with the right .yml options it will just copy labels.

I create a file like this one, name it something.yml:

```
from:
  url: https://gitlab.mycompany.biz
  token: yyyyyyy
  project: user1/project
  labelsOnly: true
to:
  url: https://gitlab.mycompany.biz
  token: yyyyyyy
  project: user2/project
  labelsOnly: true
```

Then I run:

```
./gitlab-copy something.yml
```

I had to have a working set of go tools on my computer to be able to build it, with `go get`:

```
$ go get github.com/constabulary/gb/...
```

Alternatively it might be possible to write your own more specialized provisions for sharing labels among a group of projects, using the REST apis provided by Gitlab.  I have often thought of creating one that will make one of the projects a label-master, and every other project in the group will get its labels.